# Presentation software with annotation on first monitor mirrored on second?

Tags: multiple-monitors, presentations

I am looking for some slightly specific presentation software. I basically want some software (that will work with Windows 10) that will display on the first monitor some text, and give me a bunch of tools for annotating (highlight, freehand etc.), and on the second monitor, display only the text and my annotations (updating live as they are made), and not display the buttons for tools etc.

Essentially, the output on the second monitor should be just a white screen with some black text, plus live updating annotations as I create them during the presentation. The first monitor should display the text and some buttons or whatever to select my tools.

Ideally, good touchscreen support would be good too, although I guess if it works with a mouse, it should probably be usable with a touchscreen anyway.

If anyone has any suggestions of appropriate software, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that is exactly what I wanted: http://pdfpresenter.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Oh well, hopefully my answer will be helpful to someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint can do just this. In order to enable Presenter View on a secondary monitor, go to the **Slide Show** tab, click the **Set Up Slide Show** button, and select the box for **Show Presenter View** as shown here:

[image]

With that setting enabled, the monitor not showing the slide show will display the Presenter View tools shown here:

[image]

Comment: The annotation features here are rather basic and all hidden behind one button and a bunch of menus. In the software I posted, the annotation features (while still basic) are at least presented in a way that is much quicker and simpler to switch between